# how to add haru library to Xcode 4.1 project

Tags: iphone, pdf, libharu

i recently find haro library for pdf generation and i get a iPhonepdf sample from https://github.com/akisute/iPhonePDF, the sample works fine but actually  i could nt use the library in my project, i do step by step as http://kishorek.com/?s=pdf&searchsubmit= said, but finally i got error :

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

is there  anyone to use it before to help ...

thanks in advance

Comment: Successfully add haru static library in Xcode 3.2.5 & 4.2 & its build successfully

Comment: can you explain more on how you do that, does it have any trick?

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to use **haru** library?? If it is not really needed.. then below link is really good for generating any type of **PDFs**. Also manipulating functions inside this link is really easy.. And integrations is also too easy without any additional framework and also fast.... Please follow the link

http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/

Comment: thanks, the link above does not open but i guess i saw that before but i want to use harelib,...

Comment: link is working for me i checked on other 3 pc. but anyways... sorry i dont have any idea of harelib.... best of luck..